# Getting ERROR while connecting MongoDB database to express server

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, nodemon

*Error*:
node: internal /errors :465
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err) ;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTz3c.png)

**Here is my code:**

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({ Limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));

mongoose.connect ("My Uri").
then(()=>app.listen(5000, ()=>console.log("Listening")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if your IP is whitelisted from your MongoDB atlas?